# Runtime Text Template - strange errors

Tags: c#, templates

I have this code in my runtime text template

```
  <#= Power(); #>
```

This should call a function which is defined in same class that template was defined at.

```
public partial class GallerySpecsTemplate
{
    // private fields, constructor removed

    private string Power()
    {
        string line;
        // line gets calculated
        return line;
    }
}
```

I am 100% sure it's correct class because other parts of template are using private variables from that class.

Why am I getting 4 compilation errors and how to fix them?

```
Error   1   ) expected                     
Error   2   Invalid expression term ')'    
Error   3   ; expected                     
Error   4   Invalid expression term ')'
```

When I remove that line, all 4 errors go away.

I get the same errors if I remove method `Power` from partial class definition into end of template as Class feature control block.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, same errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<#= expr #>` syntax requires an `expression` inside, not a `statement`, this is because it's compiled into `output.Write( expr );`.

...so if you put `<#= SomeFunction(); #>` then it'll be compiled to `output.Write( SomeFunction(); );` which is an obvious syntax error.

Simply remove the `;` and it will work. Simply put: the semicolon is what converts a C# `expression` into a C# `statement`.

It's the same in ASPX syntax, where `<%= expr %>` only accepts expressions, not statements (it's compiled to `Response.Write( expr );`).

Comment: Cool! Very concise answer!

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed the problem. I had no idea where to go with this and 4 errors I got are terribly misleading.